# Android persistance package?

Tags: android, database, data-persistence

I want to easily implement database connections like I would in Java EE, is there a library that can help?

Comment: Have you tried searching on internet for db connection in android, before posting here?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ActiveAndroid, it is opensource and easy to implement :)

https://www.activeandroid.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out ORMLite, it working quite good - http://ormlite.com/